# type forward slash without using single quote, double quote and semi colon filter

Tags: html, jquery, dom, filter, xss

ok, let me try a different approach.
I am not allowed to use either of the quotation  marks or semi colon.
I can get around to create a string by doing

```
let str=/^.i am a string$/
str = str.toString().slice(2, -2)
```

however I have the following string

```
http://localhost:31337/?submit=
```

because it has the / in them, I am unable to use the above method.
when I try to use /// represent 1 string, the server just chops everything and only keeps http:
I also tried to do just forward slash with

```
http:/\//glocalhost:31337/?submit=
```

but it gives me an input error.
I thought ///g escaped forward slash.
Is there a way I can build the desired string?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
I just needed to surround the string with []